# QPainter DrawImage CenterAligned

Tags: qt, qpainter

Is there any way to draw an image on `QPainter` center aligned? I see `QPainter::drawText` gives us this provision but `drawImage` does not. I have one source rect, target rect and an image. when the source size is small the image gets drawn on the left side of the page. I want it to be printed center aligned.

Answer (score 10):

The painter doesn't have a size, but the `device()` it paints on does. You can use `QRect(painter.device()->width(), painter.device()->height())` as the rectangle where you want to center your image in.

Then you'd paint the image centered like so:

```
QImage source;
QPainter painter(...);
...
QRect rect(source.rect());
QRect devRect(0, 0, painter.device()->width(), painter.device()->height());
rect.moveCenter(devRect.center());
painter.drawImage(rect.topLeft(), source);
```

Answer (score 2):

I would try to do the following (please follow the source code comments):

The sample image that should be drawn

```
// The image to draw - blue rectangle 100x100.
QImage img(100, 100, QImage::Format_ARGB32);
img.fill(Qt::blue);
```

In the paint event handler

```
[..]
QRect source(0, 0, 100, 100);
QRect target(0, 0, 400, 400);

// Calculate the point, where the image should be displayed.
// The center of source rect. should be in the center of target rect.
int deltaX = target.width() - source.width();
int deltaY = target.height() - source.height();

// Just apply coordinates transformation to draw where we need.
painter.translate(deltaX / 2, deltaY / 2);

painter.drawImage(source, img);
```

Of course you should check whether source rectangle is smaller than the target before applying this approach. I omitted that code for simplicity reasons just to demonstrate how you can center your image.

Answer (score 2):

I wanted to show a more complete example with a variable image size that stays within the bounds of the area provided to add to the other great answers.

```
void ImageView::paintEvent(QPaintEvent*)
{
  if (this->imageBuffer.empty()){ return; }

  double widgetWidth = this->width();
  double widgetHeight = this->height();
  QRectF target(0, 0, widgetWidth, widgetHeight);

  QImage tempQImage = *this->imageBuffer.at(this->imageBuffer.count()-1);
  tempQImage = tempQImage.scaled(rect().size(), Qt::KeepAspectRatio, Qt::SmoothTransformation);

  double imageSizeWidth = static_cast<double>(tempQImage.width());
  double imageSizeHeight = static_cast<double>(tempQImage.height());
  QRectF source(0.0, 0.0, imageSizeWidth, imageSizeHeight);

  int deltaX = 0;
  int deltaY = 0;
  if(source.width() < target.width())
      deltaX = target.width() - source.width();
  else
      deltaX = source.width() - target.width();

  if(source.height() < target.height())
      deltaY = target.height() - source.height();
  else
      deltaY = source.height() - target.height();

  QPainter painter(this);
  painter.translate(deltaX / 2, deltaY / 2);

  painter.drawImage(source, tempQImage);
}
```